# External screen won't turn off when closing the lid of the macbook

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

So I noticed some really annoying bug. I bought an [external screen](https://www.asus.com/Displays-Desktops/Monitors/ZenScreen/ZenScreen-MB14AC/) and connect it to my macbook pro, and I noticed that when the mac connected to power and I close the lid, the external screen still working and doesn't turn off, meaning people can still see screens although the mac is locked.

Is this a bug or some misconfiguration in the settings ?
Will really glad for some guide to fix this issue.

Comment: Some of us use our MacBooks closed, with an external screen and keyboard and trackpad/mouse. So continuing to work in that configuration is a feature, not a bug!

Comment: If you want to have the screen close then unplug the laptop